# I want to understand the following code in Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

in the following code what is code variable and what is it purpose?

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a step of the OAuth process. You exchange the code with facebook to get an access token. You can read a far better explanation than I can write, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: what is the difference between the login in this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and the login using PHP SDK or JavaScript SDK ?

Comment: that page explains both server side and client side login. php is server side. javascript is client side.

Answer (score -1):

```
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

This part is facebook suggested way to show auth. dialog which comes up usually when you try to add application. It is dialog which asking permissions to use your email, photos, etc...

```
$code
```

is most likely variable which indicates on your application side whether user with particular email exists in your DB or not.If it is empty or false it means that user does not exist and for him application shows auth. dialog